# iPhone & Mailcore memory leak problem

Tags: iphone, smtp, background, autorelease

In the app I'm currently working, I use Mailcore (http://www.mronge.com/m/MailCore/API/) to handle mail server operations. I'm trying to send a message over an SMTP connection in the background. The problem is, Leaks is telling me that I get a decent amount of memory leaks every time a message sends. I'm trying to figure if this is my fault or Mailcore's fault. Here's the code:

From my view controller:

```
-(void) send_rfq {

    CTCoreMessage *repMsg = [[[CTCoreMessage alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    NSString* msgString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date#%@\nRFQ#%@\nSalesRep#%@",[now description], [rfq_entry get_uid],[rfq_entry get_repid]];
    [repMsg setBody:msgString];
    [repMsg setSubject:@"RFQ Assign"];

    [myAppDelegate performSelectorInBackground:@selector(send_msg:) withObject:repMsg];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
}
```

From my app delegate:

```
-(BOOL) send_bg:(CTCoreMessage*) msg {
    BOOL success = TRUE;
    @try {
        [CTSMTPConnection sendMessage:msg server:smtp_server username:smtp_uname password:smtp_pass port:smtp_port useTLS:smtp_tls useAuth:smtp_auth];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        //Msg failed to send;
        success = FALSE;
    }
    return success;
}

-(void) send_msg:(CTCoreMessage*) msg {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [ [NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [msg setTo:[NSSet setWithObject:[CTCoreAddress addressWithName:@"testaccount" email:rfq_dest]]];
    [msg setFrom:[NSSet setWithObject:[CTCoreAddress addressWithName:@"RFQapp" email:rfq_src]]];
    if(![self send_bg:msg]) {
        UIAlertView * empty_alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Could not send." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [empty_alert show];
        [empty_alert autorelease];
    }
    [pool release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no leaks in the code you've posted. Either the leak is a false positive or it's elsewhere in your code. Have you tried profiling your app with Instruments? Have you tried using Build and Analyze to do static analysis of your code?

Comment: When I run "Build and Analyze", no analyzer results are returned.

I'll trying running Instruments and profiling but is this looking like a problem with the libraries?

Comment: Possibly a problem with MailCore, with which I'm not familiar. Unlikely a problem with Apple's frameworks. What is it you see leaking?

Comment: Mailcore is implemented using Libetpan (C email library). Most of the responsible frames appear to be from Libetpan's library. Things like "mailmime_fields_new" and "mailimf_date_time_new" which are functions to allocate memory. Then I get responsible frames from MailCore like "[CTCoreMessage setSubject]". Here's a stack trace of one of the leaks: http://pastebin.com/GgLypLUw

Comment: Then yes, I'd guess that MailCore is leaking. :)